# startService vs BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

Is it a good practice to send information to a Service using `startService` and `onStartCommand` continuously when compared to registering a `BroadcastReceiver`? If it's not, how does it harm?

Comment: can you please explore question a bit more ?
In many cases, we use BroadcastReceiver to know the occurance of an event and so to let service know through startService().

Answer (score 1):

As i have seen using `startService` and `onStartCommand` is a very common way to achieve talking to a service. By using broadcasts for this purpose you should concern about security problems. for example you should make your own permissions to prevent other apps to send fake broadcasts to your service or listen to your internal broadcasts. Also  sending Broadcasts has a lot more overhead as OS has to send your broadcast system wide.